# Error: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have some Firebase functions that I am hitting via Postman. This was working up until a few days ago, the only thing I can think of that changed was that I created a Firebase CI token for my CI / CD Pipeline to use when deploying to Firebase Hosting.

Everything deploys fine, but I get this error when hitting one of my functions:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

This particular function reaches out to Mail Chimp to add a user to a mailing list.

Here is my index.js for Firebase Functions:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const adminKey = require('./key/admin.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(adminKey),
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT-ID.firebaseio.com"
});


// Functions ----------
exports.general = require('./categories/general/index')
...
```

I have seen this approach mentioned in other Stackoverflow posts as well as the Firebase docs.

Here is the actual function code itself:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const axios = require('axios')
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging')
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

const logging = new Logging()
const log = logging.log('general')
const METADATA = {
  resource: {
    type: 'cloud_function',
    labels: {
      function_name: 'general-addNewSubscriber',
      region: 'us-central1'
    }
  }
}


module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const logOne = log.entry(METADATA, { event: 'addNewSubscriber:started', value: 'started', message: 'general-addNewSubscriber:started' })
            await log.write(logOne)

            const result = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'API ENDPOINT',
                auth: {
                    username: 'username',
                    password: 'password'
                },
                data: {
                    email_address: req.body.email_address,
                    status: req.body.status
                }
            })

            const logTwo = log.entry(METADATA, { event: 'addNewSubscriber:response', value: result, message: 'general-addNewSubscriber:response' })
            await log.write(logTwo)

            res.send(result)
        } catch (err) {
            const errOne = log.error(METADATA, { event: 'addNewSubscriber:error', value: err, message: 'general-addNewSubscriber:error' })
            await log.write(errOne)

            res.send(err)
        }
    })
})
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
When I remove the logging stuff the error goes away. More to come...

Comment: Are you seeing this with a deployed function, or running in the Firebase local emulator?  What is the full error message output?

Comment: @DougStevenson deployed

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a Service Account, where it's working local but not on staging, in spite of the fact that the variable and file are there.